# Is it possible to detect if a lambda has “this” in the capture group?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

In c++17 is it possible to do template meta-programming to detect if “this” was part of the capture group some how? Or at runtime?

I have a class A that accepts the lambda for later invocation. However, if the object B owning A captures “this” in the lambda it gives A, then it can cause a subtle use-after free. Being able to crash in this scenario would be valuable.

I’m aware their wouldn’t be 100% (eg a user could capture it as “a = this” or “b = (void*)this”). I also don’t expect to be able to capture all problems (eg if I capture a reference to a member variable). I’m just looking to add some confidence in the obviously wrong scenarios

Comment: Can't be done within the language. Maybe some static code analysis tool would be a better fit, even though finding a working linting rule for this seems somewhere between hard and impossible.

Comment: How would you use this information to cause a crash if a dangling reference is used? This sounds like a problem that a proper sanitizer would already solve.

Comment: The few times I needed a lambda that was passed to something else, which held a reference to `this`, I had the lambda have a `std::weak_ptr` to `this`, and made the class `std::enable_shared_from_this`, and in the lambda detected if the object was still alive.  I don't like those patterns, but it was pre-existing code that I had to improve upon.

Answer (score 7):

A lambda is *nothing more* than a class generated by the compiler that has an overloaded `operator()`. There is no mechanism in template programming that can (cross-platform) detect if a particular type was generated by the compiler, let alone introspect into the "members" of that class to figure out what it captured and how.

You will simply have to expect users of your system to exercise proper discipline.

Comment: ...until C++ has reflection.  (Insert evil laughter here.)

Comment: (and sharks with fricking laser beams)

Comment: @Eljay: It's unclear if that would work with reflection. I don't know if any of the proposals have a property to determine if a type is the result of a lambda or not. While you can introspect through private members, you don't really know if it is `this` or some other pointer to an `A`.

Comment: You could through a simplification which disallows more code than might be strictly necessary, which is to say that the thing that's processing the lambda would be given the class for which "this" is illegal & enforce there's no pointers/references to that class in the capture variables via reflection.